# componentDidMount fires twice when using TransitionGroup for animation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I'm currently using [`react-transition-group`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) in conjunction with [`react-router-dom`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy) to animate route changes and this is working fine.

The only issue I'm having is that when switching routes and I need to send or fetch some data in the `componentDidMount` life-cycle hook, it get fires twice. I'm fairly sure this is due to the `react-transition-group` but I was wondering if there is an obvious solution to this issue.

I discovered this as it was inserting an entity in the database twice, which is far from the intended behavior.

**Example of transition with logging in `componentDidMount`**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that it is an issue with my `Switch` component, [see this github issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/79)

Basically you need the `location` prop in your wrapped `Switch` component.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the snippet from the github issue so you don't have to click through.

Add location to Switch: `<Switch location={location}>`

```js
<TransitionGroup component="main">
  <CSSTransition
    key={location.pathname}
    timeout={timeout}
    exit={false}
    classNames="fade">
    <Switch location={location}> // <- Here it is!
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/blog" component={BlogList} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```